# PHP выбор символа

Tags: php, javascript, html

Есть код HTML

```
<input name="text" type="text" id="text" value="text" />
```

И код js

```
document.getElementById("text").id[3] 

>>> "x"
```

А как сделать тоже самое в PHP (приняв форму)?

```
$peremennaya = $_POST['text'][3]

>>> "x"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$peremennaya = substr($_POST['text'], 2, 1); // >>> "x"
```

Если я тебя правильно понял )

Answer (score 0):

Старик, выучи хотя бы основы JS и PHP.
У объекта `document.getElementById('text')` есть свойство `id`, оно НЕ массив и содержит значение, по которому ты искал (`'text'`).
Массив `$_POST` не бывает двумерным.
А что за `'x'` - вообще непонятно.

Comment: >Массив $_POST не бывает двумерным


Это как? То-есть ?a[]=2&a[]=3 не даст нам переменную $a которая есть массив (2,3) и мы можем обратиться к этому массиву $a[1] и $_POST["a"][1]

Comment: @boris_U, неа, йа всё же прав - сам массив `$_POST` не бывает двумерным, но никто не сказал что его содержимое не может содержать массив :)

Comment: и в итоге запись вида _POST[key][index] имеет право на жизнь

Comment: @boris_U, Я не говорил что такой записи быть не может.